# Closed-then-merged question missing "merged to" footer

Tags: bug, status-completed, user-interface, closed-questions, merged-questions

A recent change introduced [keeping merged questions around as stubs](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/06/improved-question-merging/).  I performed a couple of merges yesterday, and things appeared to be fine.

Today I ran across an old question migrated from Server Fault, and another copy that had been crossposted shortly afterwards.  The Super User copy had been appended; the migrated copy was missing an owner.  So I closed the migrated version as a duplicate, and then merged [the migrated version](https://superuser.com/questions/94266/it-takes-a-long-time-until-windows-xp-recognize-i-connected-usb-diks-closed) into [the crosspost](https://superuser.com/questions/93947/it-takes-a-long-time-until-windows-xp-recognize-i-connected-usb-drive).

After the migrated question was closed, it correctly showed the "migrated from" footer as well as the "closed by" footer.  But after the merge, only the "migrated from" footer and the "closed by" footer are displayed; the merge footer is absent.

This particular question was closed-as-duplicate, so the auto-added "Possible duplicate" link in the question body still provides a link to the right question.  But if this bug affects questions that are closed for other reasons, users will need to go to the [question history](https://superuser.com/posts/94266/revisions) to find the link to the new post.

Answer (score 14):

This will be made better in the next build (> rev 2013.3.25.887):

- we will always show the "merged by" status (provided the question is still locked or deleted)
- if a question was migrated from Site A to Site B and then merged with another question on Site B, we will not unlock Site A's question if Site B's question is deleted *(whew)*

Answer (score 2):

This is [still happening](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/132891/visually-subdue-merged-questions#comment368359_132891) and confusing (at least to me, a new mod).

I think the merge function should be streamlined. Currently, there seem to be the following steps (at least for migrated duplicates):

1. Close the duplicate
2. Merge it into the main question
3. [optional] Delete the stub.

It seems as if 1. and 3. could be done automatically by 2.

Comment: It confused me too (and I'm not a new mod).

Comment: I agree that it's frustrating when it says "you must close the question first"... well just close it for me then!