# Merge box not showing if question was migrated before being merged

Tags: bug, migration, notifications, merged-questions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [Closed-then-merged question missing “closed by” and “merged to” footers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/53322/closed-then-merged-question-missing-closed-by-and-merged-to-footers)

When a question is migrated from another site, then closed as exact duplicate and merged, the box indicating that the question was merged does not appear at the bottom of the question (see https://superuser.com/questions/310239/which-algorithm-in-truecrypt-is-the-safest-one on Super User, merged into [Which TrueCrypt Algorithm is the safest?](https://superuser.com/questions/207831/which-truecrypt-algorithm-is-the-safest)):

[image: Missing merge box in migrated and merged question]

The box that says:

> **merged by *[moderator] [at time]***
>
> this question was merged with *[question]* because it is an exact duplicate of that question.

which should appear above the "migrated" box, is missing.

Can someone look into this bug?