# Migrated question is closed as duplicate by no one?

Tags: bug, migration, closed-questions, duplicate-questions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Closed-then-merged question missing “closed by” and “merged to” footers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/53322/closed-then-merged-question-missing-closed-by-and-merged-to-footers)

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8607022/can-i-create-a-custom-text-field-and-keyboard-for-ios-w-o-subclassing-uicontrol has been migrated from [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/7064/can-i-create-a-custom-text-field-and-keyboard-for-ios-w-o-subclassing-uicontrol?noredirect=1), where its status displays correctly. On SO, however, it seems to be closed as a duplicate, or more accurately a [double-post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8600097/can-i-create-a-custom-text-field-and-keyboard-for-ios-w-o-subclassing-uicontrol).

The thing is, *it wasn't closed by anyone*:

---

[image: Shot of question in question]

<sub>The Ghost of Christmas Future, maybe?</sub>

The [timeline view](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/8607022/timeline) isn't any help either. It just shows Community adding the duplicate link. Also note that there is no link to [/revisions](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/8607022/revisions) displayed, despite it existing. **As NullUserException อ_อ ♦ points out below, however**, the revisions page does indeed show the correct history: Will ♦ closed, merged, and locked the post about an hour before I came across it.

Is this actually a bug, or does Community perhaps look for exact duplication of title and/or body when a question is migrated (as I said, the migration turned this into a double-post on SO)? If so, shouldn't there at least be a "Closed by Community ♦" banner added?

Comment: Isn't this `status-bydesign`?

Comment: Ahh, I see now. Weird

Comment: I am a wizard, harry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was closed and merged by [Will ♦](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1228/will)

You can see that through the [revision history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/8607022/revisions).

But since none of that information is directly available means this is probably a bug.

Comment: Oh, yes, I meant to include that in my post -- no link to /revisions from the question. Thanks.