# Visually subdue merged questions

Tags: feature-request, moderator-tools, design, information-display, merged-questions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Closed-then-merged question missing “closed by” and “merged to” footers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/53322/closed-then-merged-question-missing-closed-by-and-merged-to-footers)

We have had some crossposting between cs.SE and math.SE and solved the issue(s) by migrating to one site, closing one of them and merging it into the other.

Now the question list looks like this for me (moderator):

[image]

And [the closed/migrated question](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/1846/bit-xing-on-hypercubes):

[image]

There is no indication whatsoever that the closed question has been merged somewhere (and where it has been merged to). Not logged-in users (and non-mods resp. low-rep users, I assume) do not see the closed/merged question and are forwarded to the merge target when they try to visit the closed question.

Please label merged questions as such (maybe just like deleted ones?) and show the merge target.

Comment: @Raphael: Perhaps all you really need to do is delete it? The revision history says it's been merged and locked, just not deleted.

Comment: @animuson: It is not clear to me that/why I should have to do this (normal users don't see the question!). All in all, the merge function seems to be broken, given that I have to close and delete manually.

Comment: @Raphael: Normal users **do** see the question. I logged in, I clicked that question, it shows perfectly fine to me as a closed question. It's only not-logged-in users who are getting redirected. I don't know how moderator tools work, but normally merged questions are also deleted. If it's supposed to be automatic, this is a bug.

Comment: @animuson: Huh, weird. Why would logged-in users be treated differently? And where would they be sent if I deleted the question?

Comment: Wow, tons of misinformation in the comments here. Deleting with abandon. This is a case of [footer overflow](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/53322/closed-then-merged-question-missing-closed-by-and-merged-to-footers) - there's simply no support for stacking merged, closed, and migrated footers on a single question.

Comment: @Shog9: This question may be a duplicate, technically, but the linked one has not been answererd/acted upon then, imho. Jeff's answer is not satisfactory; why would I have to manually delete?

Comment: @Raphael: the stub will be deleted automatically after a while regardless - deleting it manually just removes the confusion sooner. Yeah, this should really be fixed, but it's sort of an edge-case.

Comment: @Shog9: So how do we keep this a current issue for the devs? Do they consider closed questions? Should I open a new question asking for changes to the merge function? (By the way, there are enough edge cases in the mod tools to be annoying, but that's for another day.)

Comment: You might add an answer to the question I linked, if you have something to say that's not covered there now. Old questions aren't forgotten about, this simply isn't something that's happened enough to warrant the effort it would take to fix right now (FWIW, there's a different work around that *doesn't* involve deletion, but deletion is slightly less confusing than clearing the migration history).

Comment: @Shog9: I did so, although [tag:status-bydesign] looks forbidding.

Comment: Future visitors, note that [discussion](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/53322/closed-then-merged-question-missing-merged-to-footer) lead to *not* deleting the stubs. See there for details.